Claude/Sonnet Python API - more tokens freezes, less tokens truncates
My prompt was to create a blog with 5 sections covering 5 different individuals in an industry niche.
When I had max_tokens= 300 (and then 1000), it ran quickly, but the result was not complete.
When I tried max_tokens=1500 (or 3000), then the program freezes, and doesn't come back after even about 5 minutes.  I asked Claude what to do, and it provided this code to retry, but anytime I'm over 1500 tokens, I get the timeout.
    def get_claude_response(prompt, max_retries=3, initial_max_tokens=2000, timeout=60):
        for attempt in range(max_retries):
            try:
                message = client.messages.create(
                    model="claude-3-sonnet-20240229",
                    max_tokens=initial_max_tokens * (attempt + 1),  # Increase max_tokens on each retry
                    messages=[
                        {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
                    ],
                    timeout=timeout  # Set a timeout for the API call
                )
                return message.content[0].text
            except anthropic.APITimeoutError:
                print(f"Timeout occurred. Retrying with increased max_tokens. Attempt {attempt + 1}/{max_retries}")
                time.sleep(2)  # Wait for 2 seconds before retrying
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
                return None
    
        print("Max retries reached. Unable to get a complete response.")
        return None
    
    
    # Example usage
    prompt = "details here..."
    
    print("Prompt:")
    print(prompt)
    
    
    response = get_claude_response(prompt)
    
    if response:
        print(response)
    else:
        print("Failed to get a response from Claude.")

I asked Claude itself for a solution and it came up with a method to call and get back chunks.  Although it worked, it was very slow and was 5 calls, which might be costing me more in the long run than one call with more tokens. 

def call_claude_sonnet_in_chunks(prompt, max_chunks=10, tokens_per_chunk=500, timeout=55):
    full_response = ""
    messages = [{"role": "user",
                 "content": prompt}]

    for i in range(max_chunks):
        try:
            print ("Call Claude:Sonnet i=" + str(i) + " tokens_per_chunk=" + str(tokens_per_chunk))
            message = client.messages.create(
                model="claude-3-sonnet-20240229",
                max_tokens=tokens_per_chunk,
                messages=messages,
                timeout=timeout
            )

            chunk = message.content[0].text
            full_response += chunk

            # Check if the response is complete
            if chunk.strip().endswith('.'):
                break

            # Prepare for the next chunk
            messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": chunk})
            messages.append({"role": "user", "content": "Please continue your previous response."})

            time.sleep(1)  # Small delay between requests
        except anthropic.APITimeoutError:
            print(f"Timeout occurred on chunk {i + 1}. Moving to next chunk.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
            break

    return full_response.strip()

